# Alternate div inside a while loop?

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I need to dispay three divs **alternatively** inside a **while loop**.
The first div has the class name **box-hdr5** and the second div is **box-hdr4**

Is there any way to do so? Please give me some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 0

while (true) {
  $class = ($i++ % 2 == 0) ? 'box-hdr5' : 'box-hdr4';
  echo "<div class='" . $class . "'>stuff</div>";
}
```

% is the modulus operator, which returns the remainder of integer division. The remainder will be 0 when $i is evenly divisible by 2, which will be every other time through the loop.

Comment: i guess it was supposed to work, but it is not working in mine. Dunno whats wrong...

Comment: Other than missing a semicolon on the first line, it works fine. "it is not working" is not the kind of explanation you give when you want someone to help you, since it tells as much about what problem you're having as not saying anything at all.

This was just an example of a technique to accomplish your goal. What did you do with it and what didn't work?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to have a counter and figure out whether the number is odd or even, which is easily done with the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

```
$x = 0;
while (/* true */) {
    if ($x++ % 2) {
        /* box-hdr4 */
    } else {
        /* box-hdr5 */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to do modulo by 2.

```
$alternate = false;
while (/* true */) {
    $alternate = !$alternate;
    if ($alternate) {
        // box-hdr4
    } else {
        // box-hdr5
    }
}
```

But the answers above are equally good.